# Is there any potential damage on my laptop's motherboard after SATA SSD cable overloaded and snapped?

Tags: ssd, storage

I tried to connect my new ssd sata to my laptop via extra hdd port on laptop's board with flat hdd cable but unfortunately the laptop cant detect it and after replugged the flat cable then powered the laptop on, the cable overloaded and snapped, leaving a slight burnt smell.

After unplugged the cable from my laptop, i restart the laptop and it was running flawlessly and didnt show any failure and error sign (i did several health hardware check through the software).

Still worried, is it still necesaary to check whether there are damages on board or i can confidently say that my laptop is in the good condition after the incident?

Comment: Burning is always a bad sign, but if you are satisfied with your computer as it is, use it. Short of taking it to the shop for service, there is not much more we can say.

Comment: What likely occurred is the cable wasn't fully seated, a short occurred, and the cable melted as a result. If that SATA port on the motherboard still works, it's unlikely the motherboard is damaged, but if damage did occur, it would be to the SATA port and possibly whatever SATA controller is a part of its circuit.

Comment: I am suspicious that this port that was used was actually SATA. It's unusual for a laptop to have SATA ports.  While laptops can support SATA devices, it's typically done slightly differently, then using a SATA cable.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses

yes I will check whether SATA port is still functioning normally or not and do it on the authorized service shop, thanks for the suggestions,

@Ramhound it is actually SATA I think as defined on my laptop spec for the extension:
[F571GT Specification](https://www.asus.com/id/Laptops/For-Home/Everyday-use/ASUS-F571/techspec/)
I tried to connect with WD Blue SSD SATA like shown in this [link](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-blue-sata-2-5-ssd#WDS500G2B0A)